# best practice to import bulk custom labels in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, customlabel

I want to import 20 to 25 custom labels in Lightning component. I am currently using approach below which is available in documentation.

```
import customLabel1 from '@salesforce/label/c.Custom_Label_1';
import customLabel2 from '@salesforce/label/c.Custom_Label_2';
import customLabel3 from '@salesforce/label/c.Custom_Label_3';
    ...
    ...
    ...
import customLabel20 from '@salesforce/label/c.Custom_Label_20';


export default class MyLwcComponent extends LightningElement {
    /*other logic*/

    // Expose the labels to use in the template.
    label = {
        customLabel1,
        customLabel2,
        customLabel3
        ....,
        customLabel20
    };
}
```

It is working fine, but writing these many import statements is the only way? Is there any modular way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is writing a separate js file where write all import statement of custom label and a export function.

To share code between components, create an ES6 module and export the variables or functions that you want to share.

An ES6 module is a JavaScript file that explicitly exports variables or functions that other modules can use. Modules make it easier to structure your code without polluting the global scope.

References:-

1. [Share JavaScript Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_share_code)
2. [Import/Export JavaScript file in LWC](https://www.santanuatonline.com/import-export-javascript-in-lightning-web-component/)